# Handling pop up window and checking if a new window pops up

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I am having problem with handling pop up window using robot framework. I want to choose the link from the new window which popped up after I key in the student number in the text box and click the "Retrieve" button. But, the pop up window will ONLY appear when the student number of the fail student is keyed in. If  the student number of the student who passes the exam is keyed in, it will continue filling up the marks in the respective text boxes.

For example:

**If a pop up window appears after clicking the button, click the link from the pop up window, or
else
continue key in the marks in the respective text boxes.**

I don't know how to check whether the pop up window appears or not after clicking the button and I am not very sure how to click link in the pop up window.

I am sorry if my question is confusing. I hope you all can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for java code, but you could implement similar on python

```
public boolean checkPopupWindowExists(){
    try{
        driver.switchTo().window(nameOrHandle);
    }catch (NoSuchWindowException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if switchTo().window not works try other switchTo() options (e.g. switchTo().alert with NoAlertPresentException exception).
Also check python examples [Moving between windows and frames](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) and [Popup dialogs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#popup-dialogs)